# postgres-simple - No instance for (ToRow Int) arising from a use of ‘query’

Tags: json, postgresql, haskell, haskell-spock, postgresql-simple

I am new to haskell and have honestly hard times with it. But it expands my thinking, so here we go. 
I am trying to run a really simple Webserver that queries a Postgres DB and should return the result as JSON.

The query is absolutely simple:
"Select id,data from MYTABLE where id = 1"

But the type system of haskell is killing me right now and the final type of my actions doesn't match up.
I am using [Spock](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock) and [PostgreSQL-Simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple) as a Combo.

Most tutorials are either to simple for what I want to do or to difficult. I am somewhere inbetween and miss a lot of Haskell understanding, a lot of my previous problems I have already solved by simple copy and pasting and got a simple version working.

But as soon as I try to pass on a route variable I am failing.
Here is my working version. My Database Table is here called "Envelope", The important call is where it says `get "json"` :

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module Main where

import Web.Spock
import Web.Spock.Config
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
import Data.Pool
import Data.Aeson (ToJSON(toJSON), object, (.=),Value)
import  Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.FromRow

type AppAction a = SpockActionCtx () Connection AppSession AppState a

data AppState = EmptyState
data AppSession = EmptySession

data Envelope = Envelope { envId :: Int, envData :: Value } deriving Show

instance FromRow Envelope where
  fromRow = Envelope <$> field <*> field

instance ToJSON Envelope where
   toJSON (Envelope envA envB) = object [ "id" .= envA, "data" .= envB ]

main :: IO ()
main =
  do pool<-createPool (connect (ConnectInfo "localhost" 5432 "" "" "envelopes") ) close 1 10 10
     spockCfg <- defaultSpockCfg EmptySession (PCPool pool) EmptyState
     runSpock 8080 (spock spockCfg app)

app :: SpockM Connection AppSession AppState ()
app = do 
    get root $
      text "Hello World!"
    get "json" $ do
      xs<-runQuery $ \conn -> 
        query_ conn  "select id,data from envelope where id = 1"
      json (xs::[Envelope])
```

Then I try to pass on the Envelope ID with a lambda function, for that i also need to change PostgreSQL-Simple `query_` to `query`:

```
    get ( "json" <//> var  ) $ \eid -> do
      xs<-runQuery $ \conn -> 
        query conn  "select id,data from envelope where id = ?" (eid :: Int)
      json (xs::[Envelope])
```

The error I get says:

```
 No instance for (ToRow Int) arising from a use of ‘query’
   In the expression:
      query conn "select id,data from envelope where id = ?" (eid :: Int)
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘\ conn
         -> query
              conn "select id,data from envelope where id = ?" (eid :: Int)’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      xs <- runQuery
            $ \ conn
                -> query
                     conn "select id,data from envelope where id = ?" (eid :: Int)
```

I also have problem to return just the first item from the query, even without the lambda function.

Full Source can be found on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/bjng/envelopes-server)

I hope someone has the time to help me out here.
Thanks for reading already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the error basically says is that you can't pass an `Int` to `query` as the third argument. `query` expects something that has an instance of the typeclass [`ToRow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.2.1/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-ToRow.html) and `Int` is not one. What you might want to do in your case considering you only want to pass one value to `query` is to use [`Only`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.2.1/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-Types.html#t:Only). So that line becomes:

```
query conn  "select id,data from envelope where id = ?" (Only (eid :: Int))
```

Comment: What, thats it? After all that thinking headaches ?
Thank you so much, that works. It is very confusing for me why with two parameters you can simply do ( parA:Int,parB:Int), but with oneparam  you have to do the `Only` notation. But after you pointed me towards it I found some comments on that in the Postgres-Simple Docs, so I guess I will understand it later.

Comment: In this context you can think of types like `Int` as a column and of a tuple as a row with two columns and of `Only` as a row with one column. `query` only deals with rows, so you need to place your column inside a row. This is a bit similar to using `values` in an insert statement in sql. You can't just pass 1, you need `values (1)` or `select 1`.

Comment: Makes more sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on soupis help I also find the corresponding part in the Postgres- Simple documentation. Just for completion, the docs mention an alternative Syntax, using a singleton list. So instead of using normal brackets you can use simply square brackets and it works too:

`query conn  "select id,data from envelope where id = ?" [eid :: Int]`

Additionally, in particular in my example, it makes more sense to return only the first row from the result, which then turned out to be simply straight forward with the `head` function. For anyone else who needs it, here is how you do it:

Spock and Prelude both include a `head` function. To avoid conflicts I decided to hide Spocks function since I am not using it anyway.

Add to your script at the top:

`import Web.Spock hiding(head)`

Then change the `get` part to:

```
get ( "json" <//> var  ) $ \eid -> do
      xs<-runQuery $ \conn -> 
        query conn  "select id,data from envelope where id = ?" [eid :: Int]
      json $ head (xs::[Envelope])
```

Done.